# Finding right angle coordinates on one coordinate

Tags: geometry

So I have one point $p_1(100, 100)$. I have two variables $v_1 = 3$, $v_2 = 4$. Now I need to find second point $p_2$ such that distance between the first point and the second point is $5$ (Pythagoras theorem). And the third point $p_3$ in such a way that distance between $p_1$ and $p_3$ is $3$, $p_2$ and $p_3$ is $4$. Simply other two points of the triangle from one point. How may I do this? I'm really stuck.
***GRAPHICAL REPRESENTATION***
[image: right_triangle]

Comment: If you have a starting point (the mentioned $(100,100)$) and a distance (4 or 5), the points that are this distance away from the point form a circle. Therefore, you have infinitely many solutions. Do you have any other constraints?

Comment: The only other constraint is it should be right angle triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subtract $4$ from the y-coordinate of $P_1(100,100)$ to get $P_3(100,96)$

Then you need to add $3$ to the x-coordinate of $P_3(100,96)$ to get $P_2(103,96)$

Comment: thanks. it worked